# Start Activity with MapFragment from a class that extends MainActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, webview

I working on a WebView app that communicates with my websites javascript using JavascriptInterface and I try to start MapsActivity and to mark some point on the map.

I added to my project File -> New -> Google -> Google Maps Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    ...
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, activity, regIdFirebase, mWebView, mGoogleApiClient), "WEB2Android");
    ....
```

The WebAppInterface class has many methods that are working properly, with one exception: **markPointsOnMap**

```
public class WebAppInterface extends MainActivity {
Context context;
Activity activity;
String regIdFirebase;
WebView mWebView;
Object casaMarcat = null;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public WebAppInterface(Context c, Activity a, String r, WebView w, GoogleApiClient p) {
    context = c;
    activity = a;
    regIdFirebase = r;
    mWebView = w;
    mGoogleApiClient = p;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
...
@JavascriptInterface
public void markPointsOnMap(String points) {
    Log.d("markPointsOnMap", context.toString());

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("markPoints", points);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

On the web server side i have some simple code like this

```
<p>
    <input type="button" value="Mark Points On Map" onClick="markPointsOnMap('47.179142,27.480926,KokoShannel;47.646331,26.254062,NaturelPiata;47.243562,26.716604,Jatakana;47.211149,27.014350,Placeholder')" />
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function markPointsOnMap(points) {
    WEB2Android.markPointsOnMap(points);
}
</script>
```

And I have this error:

```
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:112)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at ro.nexuserp.apps.utils.WebAppInterface$override.markPointsOnMap(WebAppInterface.java:116)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at ro.nexuserp.apps.utils.WebAppInterface$override.access$dispatch(WebAppInterface.java)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at ro.nexuserp.apps.utils.WebAppInterface.markPointsOnMap(WebAppInterface.java:0)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:41)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
 12-14 13:20:01.771 27100-28063/ro.nexuserp.apps W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I tried and this variant, but with same results.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The activity must be started from context object

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void markPointsOnMap(String points) {
   Intent i = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("markPoints", points);
   >> context.startActivity(i); <<
}
```

Uh! I lose couple of hours with this and i get and a -1 vote :)